# Why is there a big space to the left of my 5th image?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, alignment

Everything was fine yesterday… Could this be from google chrome's new update?

Everything looks fine in IE and Firefox, but now on chrome(v37) and the newest safari my 8th image will drop down below the row of images and the 5th image has a large space next to it.

I currently took off the 8th image because I am applying for jobs and I don't want the whole site to look crappy. So I temp left the one image blank.

website: http://k4design.us

**HTML**

```
<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div id="thumb1"><a href="images/1.jpg"><img src="images/1-thumb.jpg"></div>
    <div id="thumb2"><a href="http://www.socialhouseblacksburg.com">
        <img src="images/2-thumb.jpg">         
    </div>
    <div id="thumb3"><a href="images/3.jpg"><img src="images/3-thumb.jpg"></div>
    <div id="thumb4"><a href="images/4.jpg"><img src="images/4-thumb.jpg"></div>
</div>

<div class="spacer"></div>

<div class="gridContainer clearfix">
    <div id="thumb5"><a href="images/5.jpg"><img src="images/5-thumb.jpg"></div>
    <div id="thumb2"><a href="images/6.jpg"><img src="images/6-thumb.jpg"></div>
    <div id="thumb3"><a href="images/7.jpg"><img src="images/7-thumb.jpg"></div>
    <div id="thumb4"><a href="images/8.jpg"><img src="images/8-thumb.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.gridContainer {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1232px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}
#thumb1 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-top: 1.6%;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
}
#thumb2 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
}
#thumb3 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
}
#thumb4 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
}
#thumb5 {
    clear: none;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    width: 20%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25760396/chrome-automatic-shift-of-web-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you never closed the `a element` in this line:

```
<div id="thumb2"><a href="http://www.socialhouseblacksburg.com"><img src="images/2-thumb.jpg"></div>
```

Firefox can understand it, but webkit browsers don't, hence your problems with Chrome and Safari. Open Inspector in Chrome and you'll see what a mess Chrome is interpreting from your code.

Additionally, you are using a very weird approach to your coding. Just avoid all those ID and use classes, you'll have way cleaner code and less chance of errors

Comment: THANK YOU! That is the way that dreamweaver set the id/classes for me so I just went a long with it. I am trying to stay away from dreamweaver because of stuff like this.

Comment: yes I know, I didn't use DW for at least teh lsat 8-10 years because of that. Anyways, try to work with classes as much as you can, and as you're at it, use semantic code. Also, please mark this answer as accepted :)

Comment: sorry I am still new to this site and all of the rules and formatting :P